# how to show my account link in header after successfully login in magento 2.0

Tags: magento, authentication, header, toplink

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwz35.png)

I would like to show My account after login.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
       // display your link here 
    }
```

----------------------from controller-------------------

```
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
            if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
               // display your link here 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do that easily Suppose We need to show only ****My-Account**** link after sign In
We have to override the ****authorization.phtml**** file in custom theme and we can put our logic based on our requirement.

```
app/design/frontend/Namespace/Customtheme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/ authorization.phtml
```

After overriding this file we can put our login -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink $block */

$objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
$dataPostParam = '';
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
}
?>
<?php if($block->isLoggedIn() && $baseurl || $block->isLoggedIn() ) : ?>
 <li class="authorization-link" >
    <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/logout'; ?>">Sign Out</a>
</li>
 <li class="authorization-link custom-top-link-myaccount-mobile" >
   <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/'; ?>">My Account</a>
</li>
<?php else : ?>
 <li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('or')) ?>">
    <a <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLinkAttributes() ?><?= /* @noEscape */ $dataPostParam ?>>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it will work let me know if you have any issue